# Turn OFF “Authorization is required” for Google Sheets Script for own team

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We are a small company which just switched from paper to tablets (Surface GO Win10 Home) and we have one particular sheet which is used for every order (about 100 orders per month). This Google Sheet acts as a template for every single order and includes some easy code which is written in a bound Apps Script project, to handle things like switching the status from started to finished, copying some cells etc.

My problem is, when someone of the team wants to use the created "buttons" in the sheet to activate the script, it asks for authorization for the script the change the sheet. If you enable it, everything works fine but then for every new order you have to enable it again, and again, and it gets really annoying for every team member.

I tried somehow to

turn it off in the security options as administrator
tried it in the GOOGLE CLOUD PLATFORM under API's and services
tried to make the code somehow public in the script editor options
...but nothing seems not to work. I used VBA programs a lot in Excel VBA but it was more a hobby and I'm not a computer scientist, otherwise it would maybe be easier to solve this problem.

Is there an easy way so every one of my team can work with the sheets created out of a template without any request from Google for authorization every time.

Kind regards.

Comment: If there was a way to turn off authorization I don't think that they would want to tell anyone in a public forum like this.

Comment: You may want to consider a totally different angle to solve the issue. For instance, is it necessary to create a new spreadsheet file for every order? Perhaps you could just insert a new tab in one master spreadsheet per order. Or even better, [create a form](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6281888) to enter orders, and manage them in a more database-like fashion. Switching from paper to computing lets you change the workflows as well.

Comment: thank you for reply . but any thing else way to automactic accept authorrization required ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the popups is that Google Apps Script is not part of Google Sheets itself, it's a separate application that uses OAuth 2.0 to get the permissions to make the requests by calling the APIs. The popup shows the scopes you are authorizing for. This means that you can't disable that.

Note that apps script could do more things that just edit the spreadsheet itself; it could get other files, get your personal information, call external servers, etc. Also, the authentication process will only happen once per file.